# Why is my UIView not displaying correctly when updating autolayout constraints?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to animate a simple autolayout constraint change, but when I call it the first time it animates but instead of just stretching and changing the height, it moves the whole view up, if I call it again it then fixes itself.

Here is how I set up the constraints:

```
hiddenView.addSubview(topView)
                    topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    topView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

            topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

            topViewDefaultTopAnchorConstraints.append(topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.centerYAnchor))
            topViewSelectedTopAnchorConstraints.append(topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.topAnchor))

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(topViewDefaultTopAnchorConstraints)
```

And here is how I am updating them:

```
func showTopView() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(topViewDefaultTopAnchorConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(topViewSelectedTopAnchorConstraints)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Update:
Here is a gif of what happens when calling `showTopView`, calling it again fixes the bottom constraint:
[image]

It should just animate up like in the second image, not bringing the whole view up, as the `bottomAnchor` does not change, how can I fix this?

Update: I realised that I am rounding the corners of `topView` and `bottomView`, if I don't round the top corners then it works correctly, so it has something to do with this.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    topView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 100*ScreenDimensions.ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_XMAX)
    bottomView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 100*ScreenDimensions.ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_XMAX)
    topConstraint = topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.topAnchor, constant: hiddenView.frame.height/2)
    topConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your image is stretchable as it seems in image 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the `hiddenView`'s `bottomAnchor` is pulled up along with the `topView`'s bottom here. Make sure the `hiddenView`'s bottomAnchor is constrained properly. And better way to do this would be to provide a `heightAnchor` and increase the heightConstraint constant value to animate the view to increased height.

Comment: I tried `heightAnchor` instead, It still seems to move the whole thing up the first time, I'm sure the bottom anchor is properly constrained.

Comment: When using the `heightAnchor` did you remove the `topAnchor`? You should if you didn't.

Comment: Yes I replaced the `topAnchor` with `heightAnchor` but the same result. Right now I'm just making the bottom anchor extra long to compensate, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your issue is. You might need to play with the constant rather than having two different constraint defined that you activate/deactivate.

- First, define a constraint a the top of your ViewController like so:

```
var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

- Then, initialize it as shown below:

  ```
    hiddenView.addSubview(topView)
    topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    topConstraint = topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.topAnchor, constant: hiddenView.frame.height/2)
    topConstraint.isActive = true
  ```
- Then inside showTopView, you only need to update the constant and that should create the animation you are looking for:

```
    func showTopView() {
        topConstraint.isActive = false            
        topConstraint.constant = 0
        topConstraint.isActive = true            
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Similarly if you want to put the view back to normal, you'd implement it as follows:

```
    func hideTopView() {
        topConstraint.isActive = false            
        topConstraint.constant = hiddenView.frame.height/2
        topConstraint.isActive = true            
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do already have `centerXAnchor` so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer. My bad, I didn't see you had defined `centerXAnchor`.

Comment: Tried your answer, it still acts the same. Really can't seem to think why it does it, but once `showTopView()` is called again it stretches the bottom out without animating. Weird how it doesn't work the first time, Wondering if it could be something to do with the `hiddenView` but as It is behind I don't think it would be.

Comment: That's a good point. Can you post the constraints for your hiddenView?

Comment: Actually I've just realised it's definitely something to do with how I'm rounding the corners of the view, if I don't round to `topView` corners it works, and they need to be rounded in `viewDidLayoutSubViews` so when the constraints change it must break it some how. I think...

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with this approach:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let r = 100*ScreenDimensions.ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_XMAX

    topView.layer.cornerRadius = r
    topView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

    bottomView.layer.cornerRadius = r
    bottomView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

}
```